# Замена Toast на SnackBar

Tags: java, android

Есть метод который содержит toast.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_INVITE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
            Log.d(Constants.TAG_INVITES, getString(R.string.sent_invitations_fmt, ids.length));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.send_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу заменить Toast на Snackbar
Но в примерах это делается примерно следующим образом:

```
mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Пора кормить кота!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Action", null);
        mSnackbar.show();
```

Но у меня в методе нет параметра view, а если я пытаюсь объявить данный параметр, то метод же override. Поэтому в принципе и сложности.

Пытаюсь обратить к id в разметке, выбивает ошибку, код разметки:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Пытался выводить вот так:

```
    View view = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Comment: Этот view - корневой Layout разметки, на которой будет выводится Snackbar, как правило CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр `view` в случае `Snackbar` - это View, внизу которой должен отображаться `SnackBar`. обычно это корневой элемент разметки активити/фрагмента.

Т.е. вам надо передать туда что-то типа

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.content);
```

Где `content` - `ID` корневого элемента разметки активити

---

Вот описание метода `Snackbar#make()`:

```
 * <p>Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given
 * to {@code view}. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent,
 * which is defined as a {@link CoordinatorLayout} or the window decor's content view,
 * whichever comes first.
 *
 * <p>Having a {@link CoordinatorLayout} in your view hierarchy allows Snackbar to enable
 * certain features, such as swipe-to-dismiss and automatically moving of widgets like
 * {@link FloatingActionButton}.
```

Comment: Ну к примеру в моём случае это DrawerLayout. Мне туда получается нужно насильно запихнуть дополнительно и CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Нет, это не обязательно. Можно любой вью

Comment: Ну просто я объявил его и сейчас валиться приложение( обновил вопрос для наглядности.

Comment: Дополните вопрос разметкой, тем где и как снэк вызываете и логами ошибки. Скорее всего вы просто опечатались